# mongorestore to local on replica set

Tags: mongodb, mongorestore

I am trying to restore some collections to the replica server's db local.

I am gonna run some data on it. but I am getting errors. is there anyway around this?

> mongorestore --db local /dumps/
>
> ERROR: trying to write to non-master 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1)
>   isMaster info: { setName: "hosthost", setVersion: 2, ismaster: false,
>   secondary: true, hosts: [ "mongo-replica.hosthost.com:27017",
>   "mongo-temp:27017" ], primary: "mongo-temp:27017", me:
>   "mongo-replica.hosthost.com:27017", maxBsonObjectSize: 16777216,
>   maxMessageSizeBytes: 48000000, maxWriteBatchSize: 1000, localTime: new
>   Date(1479528226168), maxWireVersion: 2, minWireVersion: 0, ok: 1.0 }

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to create a minimal replica set. One way to do this is to start a Mongo shell, type `mongo` at a shell prompt, then in the **mongo shell** type something like:

`rs.initiate({ _id: "rs0", "members": [ { _id: 0, host: "localhost:27017"}]})`

where "rs0" is the name of your single member replica set. After doing this your mongorestore should work.